# I want to extract a string with escaping sign using regex in ORACLE SQL

Tags: oracle, regexp-substr

I have got a string with multiple possible ANSWERS but only one is correct:

- "shop.com\nshop.net\nvouchers.com [[WIN]]"
- "39 Euro [[WIN]]\n49 Euro\n59"
- "Euro 7 things\n12 things[[WIN]]\n21 things"

I need to extract the right/winning answer:

- "vouchers.com"
- "39 Euro"
- "12 things"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Is `\n` a newline `CHR(10)` character or a two character string composed of `\ ` slash then `n`?

Comment: \n is within the string - a two character string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data contains newline `CHR(10)` characters then you can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^(.*)\[\[WIN\]\]$', 1, 1, 'm', 1) AS match
FROM   table_name
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (value) AS
SELECT 'shop.com
shop.net
vouchers.com [[WIN]]' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '39 Euro [[WIN]]
49 Euro
59' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Euro 7 things
12 things[[WIN]]
21 things' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | MATCH |
> | --- |
> | vouchers.com |
> | 39 Euro |
> | 12 things |

---

If your data contains `\n` two-character substrings then:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '^(.*\\n)?(.*?)\[\[WIN\]\]\s*($|\\n)', 1, 1, NULL, 2)
         AS match
FROM   table_name
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1f81338f920739ecf87cb68caaa8d487)*

Comment: thank u for your answer with both expressions i get the result null

Comment: @TobiasG. The db<>fiddle linked in the answer does not give `NULL` for any of your examples. If you are getting different results then please give an example with the data as `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements we can copy-paste because I cannot replicate your `NULL` outputs.

Comment: if i replicate it with your code and create the new table, it is correct, if i use the table from my database with its value the outcome is null. i tried to copy the value and paste it to notepad++ i got this result:
"39 Euro [[WIN]]
\n49 Euro
\n59 Euro" with breaking lines

Comment: i meant with hyphenates " and breaking

Comment: @TobiasG. That is because your data does not match the question you asked and has white-space after the `[[WIN]]` substring. I've updated the answer but if you don't give us the correct input then the answer you get will be for the incorrect values and may not work.

Comment: thank you - now i get the correct results out of the database